# Programatically show tooltip in Live Charts

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I have an application that have 2 charts as follows:

[image: Charts Example]

Is it possible to programatically show the tooltip of the second chart when hovering on the first chart - via chart 1's DataHover event?

*EDIT*

The info on the second chart is for Relative Strength Index. It is usually presented at the bottom of the chart. For this reason I made it a separate chart.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an answer to my question, here is what I did. A now deleted comment asked why there are two charts. When I did it like that initially, the charts were over each other.

So I simply went back to that, and applied a scaling factor. 20% of the chart are is fine for the RSI, and as RSI is always calculated out of 100, I set the axis max value to 500% as follows:

```
chartMain.AxisY.Add(new Axis
{
  MaxValue = 500,
  MinValue = 0,
  IsMerged = true,
  Position = AxisPosition.RightTop,
  ShowLabels = false,
  Sections = new SectionsCollection
  {
    new AxisSection
    {
      SectionWidth = m_TradeManager.Settings.RSIThreshold,
      Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush
      {
        Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(254,132,132),
        Opacity = .4
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The end result is this:

[image: Chart Example]